# How to fix Api Error: Required parameter: project in GAE with GCS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am getting the following error when trying to connect with a Google Cloud Storage Bucket in a nodejs app based in the Google App Engine.

> ApiError: Required parameter: project
>
> ```
>    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:208:38)
>
>    at Util.handleResp (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:149:117)
> ```

The code to connect in the server.js file is pretty straightforward:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
storage.getBuckets().then(y => console.log(y));
```

Both the deployed app and storage bucket are part of the same project.

I have also created a service account for the storage bucket, which has API Keys Admin and Storage Admin roles, and API keys have been generated.

Any help would be much appreciated!

## Edit:

Here is the updated code (with my project id edited):

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'r@@@@@@t-t@@@h-3####9'
});

storage.getBuckets().then(y => console.log(y));
```

### package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.15.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.6.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the client and specify the Project ID (not the project name):

```
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'your-project-id'
});
```

If you want to specify the service account that you mentioned:

```
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/service-account-key.json'
});
```

Documentation:

[Google Cloud Storage Nodejs Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but even when specifying the Project Id, I'm getting the same error. Maybe I am using the wrong value, I used the project_id value that was in the service account key file. Are there maybe some settings in GCP that need to be updated?

Comment: @nm_machine89 The settings are as simple as my answer. Note: the service account project ID is the Project ID that owns the service account. That does not mean which project(s) or resources the service account has permissions to. If you have the same error, then you implemented my answer incorrectly.

Comment: The Project Id I have used is the same one that shows under Project Info on the Home Dashboard. I copied the lines that you provided into my code and replaced the project id. I'm aware of how simple this is hence why I am so stumped that I am getting this error.

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are using (the exact code). Consult the link to the API documentation. Make sure that the code is actually executing. The error message is very specific. You have not included the required parameter.

Comment: Note: The error message is not about the project ID value. The error message is about the project parameters not being specified. One item I just noticed. The message says **project** and not **projectId**. Are you using old code or old libraries?

Comment: The google cloud storage dependecy in my package.json file is : "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.15.3". I have no other google related dependencies.